# Google cloud functions v2 cloud build permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy cloud functions v2 using v2 repository. However, the deploy fails with permissions error and no real error message. How do I even start to debug this? I am under the impression that I am giving excessive permissions to all the service accounts involved and I just just trying to deploy a function that returns "test" so there should be no complexity here.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed?

Here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  args:
  - gcloud
  - functions
  - deploy
  - testFuncHandler
  - --gen2
  - --region=us-central1
  - --source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/learninfra002/repos/MaxYuan85-learninginfra/fixed-aliases/main/paths/server
  - --service-account=functions@learninfra002.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - --run-service-account=server@learninfra002.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - --trigger-http
  - --runtime=nodejs16
```

and the permissions

[image]

In my terminal I run the following:

```
gcloud builds submit --region=us-central1 --config ../infra/deploy/functions/cloudbuild.yaml
```

And here is the error message

```
starting build "13623ac8-86cd-4c9f-9391-8067fa022dea"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://learninfra002_cloudbuild/source/1684601532.672615-5bfbfaf13b864d5197de071358cd9a7c.tgz#1684601533175833
Copying gs://learninfra002_cloudbuild/source/1684601532.672615-5bfbfaf13b864d5197de071358cd9a7c.tgz#1684601533175833...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/144.7 KiB]                                                
/ [1 files][144.7 KiB/144.7 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/144.7 KiB.                                    
BUILD
Pulling image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
918547b94326: Already exists
...
e298498ccbf4: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6a8a85c6c68b1d85621f61d46c5a8e49cb2420193ad1f4f12dd766f75ee30d87
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
Preparing function...
...........done.
Updating function (may take a while)...
failed
Failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=7, message=Could not build the function due to missing permissions. Error determining source provenence
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: FYI for the Google SDK. The word `provenence` in the error message is misspelled.